# Get a random row from the table using Kohana3 framework - fast

Tags: php, mysql, kohana-3

How to make this code worked in Kohana3 framework? I have a syntax problem with it.

```
ORM::factory('table1')
->where ( 'id', '=', ceil( DB::expr('rand()')  * [SELECT max(id) from table1] ) )
->find();
```

That's how I want to select a random row from the table.

This works fine for small tables (that contains than 1000 rows), but not for big tables:

```
ORM::factory('table1')
->order_by(DB::expr('RAND()'))
->find();
```

The standard mysql equivalent of what I want is something like this:

```
SELECT name
  FROM table1 JOIN
       (SELECT CEIL(RAND() *
                    (SELECT MAX(id)
                       FROM table1)) AS id
        ) AS r2
       USING (id);
```

So, how to convert that into a working code for Kohana3 framework?

P.S. This method works fine if there are no holes (no deleted rows) in the table, and that's fine in my case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are trying to do is really a problem with MySQL. You need the right query to have it perform for any size table. A more scalable implementation is to use PHP to generate a random number less than the max ID and then select on that.

Get the highest ID:

```
SELECT MAX(id) max_id FROM table1
```

In PHP get the "id" to select:

```
$rand_id = mt_rand(0, $max_id-1);
```

Then create your query to select a random record, using a LIMIT 1 so it works even if there are holes.

```
SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE id>=$rand_id ORDER BY id LIMIT 1
```

Doing it all in MySQL can be done, but it's not going to be easy to read or implement with a DB abstraction layer.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I did it the same way. Your answer says I'm on the right track. The only difference is about the last query string. I think it is not a good idea to cover the holes using id>= because you are trying to sort it order by. That's from what I started saying about low performance of sort_by for large tables.
So, I would use id= instead of id>= and check afterwards if the row exists. If not, repeat the procedure. That way the values have discrete uniform distribution (that's the most programmers want when try to select a random row from the table).

Comment: Sorting by an index, especially by the primary key, is very fast. You can always drop the ORDER BY. MySQL with then returns the first record it finds greater than the id specified. It may not be the next highest one.

Comment: So your purely using ORDER BY so MySQL doesn't through a random row at you? But isn't that what we want!? I'm just forgetting the ORDER BY syntax.

Comment: No, MySQL doesn't do anything random, you pick a random ID. Like turning to a random page in a book. The book can't give a random page, so you pick one between 1 and the number of pages. Maybe someone ripped out the page, so you go to the next available one.